# Does a representation being faithful on certain Lie subalgebras imply that this representation is faithful on the Lie algebra?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak{g}$ be a semisimple Lie algebra, $V$ be a vector space, and $R:\mathfrak{g}\rightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V)$ be a representation of $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\{X\}\subsetneqq\mathfrak{g}$ be a generating(in the Lie algebra sense) subset of $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. $\mathfrak{g} = \langle \{X\} \rangle$. Let $\mathfrak{h}$ be a strict Lie subalgebra generate by a subset of $\{X\}$, and denote by $H$ all such $\mathfrak{h}$. Then is the following statement true?

If the representation $R$ restricted on $\mathfrak{h}$ is faithful for all $\mathfrak{h}\in H$, then $R$ is a faithful representation of $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: What is the "Lie algebra of permutations" that you mentioned in a comment to my deleted answer?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I mean consider group members of S_n as generators of a Lie algebra, defined with the usual Lie bracket, and multiplication is defined as in S_n.

Comment: What is the "usual Lie bracket" and what does it have to do with "multiplication as defined in $S_n$"? Do you mean to take the commutator in the group algebra of $S_n$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What I was trying to show is that consider the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ generated by $k$ permutations of $n$ objects. If a representation is faithful on all the Lie algebra of $k$ permutations on arbitrary $k$ objects, then it’s faith on $\mathfrak{g}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Yes, that’s what I mean.

Comment: This algebra isn't semisimple! $\mathbb{C}[S_n]$ is a direct product of copies of matrix rings $M_d(\mathbb{C})$ so its commutator Lie algebra is a direct product of copies of $\mathfrak{gl}_d(\mathbb{C})$, which is only reductive.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan You are exactly right! I should have said that I am only interested in the semisimple part of the algebra.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Hi! Just let you know that I am really grateful to your comment on my deleted answer that "for a simple Lie algebra a representation is faithful as soon as it's nontrivial". I was able to use this fact to prove my original question about the Lie algebra of permutations.

Comment: I don't understand "Let $\{X\}\subsetneqq\mathfrak{g}$ be a generating subspace of $\mathfrak{g}$, i.e. $\mathfrak{g} = \langle \{X\} \rangle$." Do you mean that a) $X$ is a sub-*vector*-space of $\mathfrak g$ such that the *Lie algebra generated by* $X$ is all of $\mathfrak g$ -- or: that b) $X$ is some sub*set* of $\mathfrak g$ such that the *vector space generated by* $X$ is all of $\mathfrak g$ -- or: that c) $X$ is some sub*set* of $\mathfrak g$ such that the *Lie algebra generated by* $X$ is all of $\mathfrak g$? Please clarify.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Sorry for the confusion. I really mean c), but I thought a) and c) are equivalent. I will clarify it in the question.